# SPSS Means With Missing Values

Tags: mean, missing-data, spss

I am averaging the percentages of teaching times of different types of faculty over the span of 3 years. The averaged percentages need to add up to 100%, but they don't because there are missing values. Is there a way to count missing values when I use the mean functions?

```
'''
    aggregate outfile=* /break car cip control
      / ncount = n
      / {5}
      = mean({0} to {1}).
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want missing values to count as Zeros, you could either recode them so before aggregating

```
recode YourVar (miss=0).
```

Or without touching the missing values in advance you can use the `aggregate` command to calculate the sum and the number of rows and afterwards divide `sum/n` which should give you the mean without discounting the missing values.